# Laravel update Issue

Tags: php, laravel-4

Here is my code -

```
$updatecompany = DB::table('Companies')
                ->where('ID', (int)$companyid)
                ->update(array(
                    'CompanyName'    => $companyname,                   
                    'CompanyAddress' => $companyaddress,
                    'CompanyEmail'   => $companyemail,
                    'ContactName'    => $contactname,
                    'CompanyCity'    => $companycity,
                    'CompanyState'   => $companystate,
                    'CompanyZip'     => $companyzipcode,
                    'CompanyPhone'   => $companyphone,
                ));
```

`$updatecompany` is always `0`. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One of most possible reasons is that you are updating with the same data in the database.

There needs one out of the box solution, of course if you can do it.

So, no rows are updating, even if the SQL is correct.

Here is my suggestion:

Add a new column `updatedOn` in DB Table `Companies`.

The type should be `TIMESTAMP` and add attribute `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

This way you will always get row affected and hence you get return value other than `0`.

Comment: Same if i change the values.

Comment: The issue was with the id. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast `$companyId` to an integer there. It does not help Laravel's query builder.

Use `dd($companyId)` and dump the variable before you run the query and find out what it is.

Comment: The issue was with the id. Solved.

Comment: good. I recommend you use only lower case for your db columns as well.